# How to Instantiate a game object in the same location in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am trying to instantiate levels into my game but when i instantiate the first level it spawns right of my spawn location reference and then when i delete the first level and spawn the second level in game play the second level spawns right of the first level.
so basically i have a game object in my scene as a position reference but when ever i instantiate the new level is move more and more to the right.

How do i get it to spawn at the location reference every time?

I instantiate the first level in the following way at the start of the game:

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Instantiate(levels[levelIndex], levelPosition.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

and then when the level no longer has zombies in it the current level is destroyed and the next one is instantiated in the following way:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    zombies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Zombie");
    zombieCount = zombies.Length;
    if (zombieCount == 0) LoadNewLevel();
}

private void LoadNewLevel()
{
    var levelDestroy = GameObject.Find("Level" + level + "(Clone)");
    Destroy(levelDestroy);

    level++;
    levelIndex++;

    if (levelIndex < 2) Instantiate(levels[levelIndex], levelPosition.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

How do i get it to always spawn at the reference location

Answer (score 0):

Try logging `levelPosition.transform.position` when you instantiate because that's where it's going. If that position is correct then check the thing your instantiating and make sure your objects are all in a position that correctly accounts for your levelPosition value. If you're wanting it to spawn at x=2 for example and you're using 2 for x in both the instantiation position AND in the level prefab then you're ending up with a total x offset of 4 which would be farther right than you intended.

Comment: I have logged the position, and every time it logs the correct values (the values of the levelPosition reference) but the game object does not instantiate into the scene in the correct place. Even though if i look at the values in the inspector of the level its displaying the correct values for all x,y & z values. and also my levels values are all set to 0 in the prefab well the center of the complete level is set to 0